# IF multiple conditions

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

F.e. there is some folder on user's desktop. I want to remove any files within this folder except shortcuts. There are two types of shortcuts - to some local\network resources and shortcuts to some sites.

"shortcuts on some local\network resources" have .lnk extension

"shortcuts to some sites" have .url extension

I've [already found](https://superuser.com/questions/910036/delete-all-files-in-the-folder-except-one-extensionsay-idf-using-batch-file) how to do this task separately

```
forfiles /p "%userprofile%\Desktop\folder" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c for %G in (@path) do @if /I [%~xG] neq [.lnk] del /F /Q %G"
```

and

```
forfiles /p "%userprofile%\Desktop\folder" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c for %G in (@path) do @if /I [%~xG] neq [.url] del /F /Q %G"
```

But how to combine these conditions into one string? Something like `if /I [%~xG] neq [.lnk] AND [.lnk]` ...

Comment: `if /I "%~xG" neq [.lnk] if /I "%~xG" neq [.url] ...`

Comment: (although some purists will note you shouldn't do `neq` with strings, but `if not ... == ...` instead - both work fine)

Comment: I'd also add `of @isdir == FALSE` after `cmd /C` and before any further commands...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely no need to use a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) within your [forfiles](/questions/tagged/forfiles) `/C` command.

Try either;

```bat
ForFiles /P "%UserProfile%\Desktop\folder" /S /C "Cmd /C If /I Not @ext==\"lnk\" If /I Not @ext==\"url\" Del /A /F @path"
```

Or use the hex codes as shown in the help information, available at the Command Prompt by entering, `forfiles /?`

```bat
ForFiles /P "%UserProfile%\Desktop\folder" /S /C "Cmd /C If /I Not @ext==0x22lnk0x22 If /I Not @ext==0x22url0x22" Del /A /F @path"
```

Comment: /Q instead /A for confirmation suppression
I cannot edit your comment because "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" :-)

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not in the habit of changing a correct command to another incorrect one. Open a Command Prompt window and read the help information for the command, either `del /?`, `erase /?`, `help del` or `help erase`. You'll note that the `/Q` option is only used when deleting one or more files using a wildcard. You're not using a wildcard, but a fully qualified file name. The `/A` option is used to select, for instance, read only files, _(you've already used the `/F` option for deleting read only files)_. Without an attribute, the `/A` option selects all, i.e. `R`, `S`, `H`, `A`, `I` and `L`.